# Proof of multi-variable limit

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

So I am trying to show that $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)}\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}=1 $$
I seem to be doing my scratch work(in order to find $\delta$) wrong. Is this correct?
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}-1\right |
&= \frac{2\left|x\right |\left|y\right |}{x^2+y^2}-1
&\leq  \frac{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2+y^2} -1
&= 2-1=1
< \epsilon
\end{align}
If not, then can someone please provide with a full-proof of how this will be tackled and what are we to take $\delta$ as including the corresponding scratch work?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.  The limit does exist at $(1,1)$

Comment: @DougM Would you know how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote what follows, first, and then came to the conclusion that it is totally overkill.

The numerator is continuous at $(1,1).$
The denominator is non-zero and continuous at the same point.  Therefore $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(1,1).$

$\lim_\limits{(x,y)\to(1,1)} f(x,y) = f(x,y)$

And if you want to kill it.

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0: d\big( (x,y),(1,1)\big)<\delta \implies \left|\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}-1\right |<\epsilon$

$\left|\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}-1\right |\\
\left|\frac {x^2 - 2xy + y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right |$

We need to show that:

$x^2 - 2xy + y^2 \le k\delta$

For some bounded k.
We can choose the distance metric which is most convenient to use.

And that
$x^2+y^2>0$ with an appropriately bounded $\delta$

Suppose $d\big( (x,y),(a,b)\big) = |x-a|+ |y-b|$  I will leave it to you to show that this is a valid metric.

$x^2 - 2xy + y^2 = (x-y)^2 = \big((x-1) - (y-1)\big)^2$

$d\big( (x,y),(1,1)\big) < \delta \implies ((x-1) + (y-1))^2<\delta^2$

Let $\delta \le 1$

$\frac 14 \le x^2+y^2 \le 5$

let $\delta = \min (1, \frac {\epsilon}{4})$

Comment: Wait, so I got everything perfectly except for how we arrived at $1/4 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 5$ by letting $\delta \leq 1$?

Comment: Using this metric (I forget the name of it) the set of points $1$ unit from $(1,1)$ form a diamond bordered by $x-y = 1, x-y = -1, x+y = 3, x+y = 1$  The point on this $x^2 + y^2$ is the distance in the euclidean metric from the origin.  And the closest point on that diamond is $(0.5,0.5)$ and the most distant points are $(1,2),(2,1)$